# Neural network output layer activation

Tags: deep-learning

I am familiar with Keras and in Keras we need add activation function in output layer as per requirement but while learning Tensorflow I found no activation function is added to output layer.

Can anyone explain the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no activation function required for the output layer in Keras either.

For **classification** tasks, we generally tend to add an activation function in the output ("sigmoid" for binary, and "softmax" for multi-class, etc.).

However, in most cases, people don't add an activation function in the output layer for **regression** neural network tasks (example below), because we need the real continuous output value in the end.

```
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow the losses function in general requires *logits* as input such as [sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) or [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy). *Logits* are the output before the activation function.

In Keras however, per default, you need to pass the output (with the activation) to compute your loss, as you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6612da89516247503f03ef76e974b51a434fb52e/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3838) for the `categorical_cross_entropy`, if what you pass to the loss is not a logit (got an activation function) (which is the default) it computes the cross-entropy based directly on the output, but if it's coming from logits, you'll have to specify the `from_logits=True`, and it will use the corresponding TF loss function that expect logits as input.